# How to fetch details from wp_users id don't know in which format wordpress store password

Tags: php, wordpress, api

How to fetch details from wp_users id don't know in which format wordpress store password

```
$user_login = $_REQUEST['user_login'];
$pwd = md5($_REQUEST['user_pass']);


$sql = "SELECT * from wp_users where user_login='$user_login' and user_pass='$pwd'";
            $sqlQuery = mysql_query($sql);
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($sqlQuery);
            if($numrows > 0)
            {
                while($loginResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery)){


                    $loginId = $loginResult['user_login'];
                    $email = $loginResult['user_email'];

                    $respond = array("id"=>$loginId,"email"=>$email);

                }

                 echo '{"response": {"message":{"message":"Login Successfully"},"userInfo":'.json_encode($respond).'},"success":true}';

                }else{
                $message = array("message"=> "Invalid Credentials");
                echo '{"success":false,"message":'.json_encode($message).'}';

            }
```

all the time when this hit it does not shows me Invalid Credentials because of password does not match i guess. please provide a good solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used [wp_authenticate_username_password()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate_username_password/)

Authenticate a user, confirming the username and password are valid

```
$userName = $_POST['user_login'];
$password = $_POST['user_pass'];
$check = wp_authenticate_username_password( NULL, $userName , $password );
```

You can then simply check the result with

```
if(is_wp_error( $check ))
{
  echo 'Wrong'; 
}
else
{
  echo 'Correct';
}
```

Comment: do it need library for using wp_authenticate_username_password() method if yes than which one how can is used in above method

Comment: No need to any library for this. It wordpress default functionality

Comment: so what will be query can you explain that i made how it is used i am confused

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * from wp_users where wp_authenticate_username_password( NULL, $user_login , $pass );"; used this 1 but does not effective

Comment: no need any query only pass UserName  Password in wp_authenticate_username_password( ).

Comment: Please check this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate_username_password/

Comment: This function are used for Authenticate a user, confirming the username and password are valid.

Comment: i am nothing getting if i print $check variable no error no msg if i checked if(is_wp_error( $check )) as well

Comment: @James in which page add this code.it's wordpress page or you create new php page in wordpress

Comment: I created new php page what to include to call this method on it

Comment: @James you need to include `wp-load.php` file in you file.this file is located in root folder

Answer (score 1):

one way is-

Wordpress stores the password using wp_hash_password() function.

You can pass the user password in the function and it will return the encrypted password.

keep in mind that function is written in wp-includes/pluggable.php

another way is-

```
include '/wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
$hash = $user->user_pass;
$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
$check = $wp_hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hash);
```

If $check is true, they match.

the reason you can't generate the same hash twice is because of the use of a salt. Salting the password when hashing makes the hash harder to hack using dictionary attacks. This is why generating the hash again and comparing won't work. The hash isn't the same every single time. The check function takes part of the hash (the salt) and the password and recomputes the hash with that salt, thus allowing it to check properly.

hope it helps